# How to express infinity in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, infinity

Is there a keyword to express Infinity in Ruby?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**If you use ruby 1.9.2, you can use**:

```
>> Float::INFINITY #=> Infinity
>> 3 < Float::INFINITY #=> true
```

Or you can create your own constant using the following*:
I've checked that in Ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and 1.9.2 you have [Float.infinite?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Float.html#M000147).

```
PositiveInfinity = +1.0/0.0 
=> Infinity

NegativeInfinity = -1.0/0.0 
=> -Infinity

CompleteInfinity = NegativeInfinity..PositiveInfinity
=> -Infinity..Infinity
```

<sup>*I've verified this in Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.9.2</sup>

Comment: Right. I tried doing comparisons between any integer and that value and it seems to be working fine. I am just wondering now if this is safe!

Comment: There's a nice article here describing the properties of Infinity in Ruby (including Infinity derived via dividing by 0): http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-infinity/ - should give you an idea whether or not it's safe. (For what it's worth, IMHO messing around with numeric Infinity values is virtually never safe or truly needed regardless of what programming language you're using, unless you're doing actual math-related work)

Comment: This is great, thanks, I believe you can also do `-Float::INFINITY` for negative infinity.

Answer (score 103):

No keyword, but 1.9.2 has a constant for this:

```
>> Float::INFINITY #=> Infinity
>> 3 < Float::INFINITY #=> true
```

Comment: +1, I didn't realize this was in 1.9.2. I've updated my answer directing people to your answer if that is the version they are targeting.

Answer (score 8):

[Consider BigDecimal in the ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#label-Infinity)

```
1.9.3p429 :025 > BigDecimal('Infinity')
 => #<BigDecimal:7f8a6c548140,'Infinity',9(9)>
1.9.3p429 :026 > BigDecimal('-Infinity')
 => #<BigDecimal:7f8a6a0e3728,'-Infinity',9(9)>
1.9.3p429 :027 > 3 < BigDecimal('Infinity')
 => true

1.9.3p429 :028 > BigDecimal::INFINITY
 => #<BigDecimal:7f8a6ad046d8,'Infinity',9(9)>
```