# How can I simplify this piece of code?

Tags: ruby

How can I simplify this piece of code?

```
if number < 100
    divisor = 10
elsif number < 1000
    divisor = 100
elsif number < 1000000 # 1 million
    divisor = 1000
elsif number < 1000000000 # 1 billion
    divisor = 1000000
elsif number < 1000000000000 # 1 trillion
    divisor = 1000000000
# Keep goin...
end
```

The point here is...

- If the number is `>= 0` and `< 100` I need a `divisor = 10`.
- If the number is `>= 100` and `< 1.000` I need a `divisor = 100`.
- If the number is `>= 1.000` and `< 1.000.000` I need a `divisor = 1.000`.
- If the number is `>= 1.000.000` and `< 1.000.000.000` I need a `divisor = 1.000.000`.
- This keeps goin forever..

I tried a few combinations of `while` and `pow`, but I don't get the pattern here.

Comment: Looks like you have two patterns here. Think about the logic you used to decide on those values in the first place and it will probably lead to the answer (or is it not your code?)

Comment: have you tried using `for-loop` and `modulus` operator?

Comment: elsif number < 1000000 # 1 million
    divisor = 1000 for this you required 1000 or 100000

Comment: [`Math.log10`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#method-c-log10) is your friend if you know how to use it and what the domain of the `log` function is (sticking to **R** of course).

Comment: I have updated the question with more info, I've already tried `Math.log10`... maybe I misused it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def divisor num
  10 ** (num < 1000 ? Math.log10(num).to_i : Math.log10(num).to_i / 3 * 3)
end

divisor(99) # => 10
divisor(999) # => 100
divisor(999_999) # => 1_000
divisor(999_999_999) # => 1_000_000
divisor(999_999_999_999) # => 1_000_000_000
```

Or, more compactly:

```
def divisor num
  ->a{10 ** (a < 3 ? a : a / 3 * 3)}.call(Math.log10(num).to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   divisior = 10**(number.to_s.length - 1)
```

as per given condition
it will give you result .

Comment: With `number = 28456` we got `10 ** 5-1` == *10000* and not *1000*

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can calculate the divisor. See [Dnyans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495597/676874).

If you have a similar problem and you can't calculate the result, but want to avoid the `if`-`elsif` structure, then you could use `case`:

```
case number 
  when 0...100
    divisor = 10
  when 100...1000
    divisor = 100
  when 1000...1000000 # 1 million
    divisor = 1000
  when 1000000...1000000000 # 1 billion
    divisor = 1000000
  when 1000000000...1000000000000 # 1 trillion
    divisor = 1000000000
# Keep goin...
  else
end
```

To implement the `< 100` is a bit [more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778295/how-to-express-infinity-in-ruby):

```
NegativeInfinity = -1.0/0.0 
case number 
  when NegativeInfinity...100
    divisor = 10
  when 100...1000
    divisor = 100
  when 1000...1000000 # 1 million
    divisor = 1000
  when 1000000...1000000000 # 1 billion
    divisor = 1000000
  when 1000000000...1000000000000 # 1 trillion
    divisor = 1000000000
# Keep goin...
  else
end
```

If you want to avoid to assign `divisor` each time, you could use the result of the `case`-command:

```
divisor = case number 
  when NegativeInfinity...100
    10
  when 100...1000
    100
  when 1000...1000000 # 1 million
    1000
  when 1000000...1000000000 # 1 billion
    1000000
  when 1000000000...1000000000000 # 1 trillion
    1000000000
# Keep goin...
  else
end
```

And combined with [sawas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496809/676874) you can make it for all values:

```
divisor = case number 
  when 0...100
    10
  when 100...1000
    100
  else
    (10 ** (Math.log10(number).to_i / 3 * 3))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=number
divisor=10
(x/=10;divisor*=10) while x>=100
```