# Using a case/when checking a negative number

Tags: ruby

```
number = -5

case number
when number < 0
  return "Please enter a number greater than 0."
when 0..1
  return false
when 2
  return true
end
...
```

I expected it to return "Please enter a number greater than 0", but instead it returned nil.  Why is that? How can I check if the number is less than 0?

Comment: What is the expected return?

Comment: @sawa I was expecting it to return the first when like an `if` would. I understand how it works now thanks to @ashwilson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you give a variable to `case`, it's compared against each `when` clause with the `===` method. The first `===` to return `true` will be the branch that's executed.

In your case, `number < 0` is evaluating to `true`, and `-5 === true` is false!

What you want to do is either leave the `number` off of the `case`, and make all of the `when` clauses boolean:

```
case
when number < 0
  return "Please enter a number greater than 0."
when number.between?(0, 1)
  return false
when number == 2
  return true
end
```

Or leave the number on, but make *all* of the `when`s values that you can compare against:

```
case number
when -Float::INFINITY..0  # or (-1.0/0)..0 
  return "Please enter a number greater than 0."
when 0..1
  return false
when 2
  return true
end
```

Comment: Great explanation. Can you give me a better understanding of `-Float::Infinity..0` or perhaps a link? Thanks.

Comment: Well, since you want that `when` to execute for any negative number, the range of all negative numbers is `-Infinity` to `0`, or `-Float::INFINITY..0` (and, like Doorknob of Snow said below, `Float::INFINITY` was introduced in 1.9.2). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778295/how-to-express-infinity-in-ruby

Comment: should be `...`, not `..`, otherwise you catch `0`

Answer (score 4):

`when number < 0` will be the same as `when true` in this case, because `number` is indeed less than zero, and the `when` will not be entered since `-5 != true`.

You could try

```
when (-1.0/0)..0 # negative Infinity to 0
```

Or, if you're using 1.9.2 or above:

```
when -Float::INFINITY..0
```

Comment: should be `...`, not `..`