# RoR: Is there a value for infinite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, max, infinity

I am trying to set up a `max_users` method. I have two different software types, hardware and software, and I am trying to set hardware to 1, and software to unlimited (eventually the user will choose in a form field how many max users they want, but for now just unlimited.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here's my model code:

```
def set_max_users
  if max_users.nil?
    self.max_users = 1
  end
end
```

And my JS that I'm using to dynamically add form fields with cocoon(in case this would help at all):

```
$ ->
  check_to_hide_add_link = ->
    max_users = parseInt($("#asset_max_users").val(), 10)
    if $("#assets_users .nested-fields").length >= max_users
      $("#assets_users .links a").hide()
    else
      $("#assets_users .links a").show()

  $("#assets_users").bind "cocoon:after-insert", ->
    check_to_hide_add_link()

  $("#assets_users").bind "cocoon:after-remove", ->
    check_to_hide_add_link()

  check_to_hide_add_link()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asked and answered here: [How to express infinity in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778295/how-to-express-infinity-in-ruby)

but the short of it is:

`Float::INFINITY`

Comment: Thank you. I was told there wasn't a way to have infinity, but now I know there is.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use Infinity in Ruby, you will not be able to save Infinity value to DB.
As a workaround, you can set it to 0 (if you don't need max_user to be equal to 0, else you can just use nil/empty value) - as a result you'll just need to check if the value is 0, then it's Infinite and no need to check for more/less of other value. It will solve one more problem, users cannot set Infinity as a numeric field value.

```
check_to_hide_add_link = ->
  max_users = parseInt($("#asset_max_users").val(), 10)
  if max_users isnt 0 and $("#assets_users .nested-fields").length >= max_users
    $("#assets_users .links a").hide()
  else
    $("#assets_users .links a").show()
```